# Is there anything like 'minimizing stack overflow of an array' in C language?

Tags: c++, c

Someone was telling me about minimizing the stack overflow of an array in C that i can do it by filling an array from both sides that is left to right and right to left, something like that. but basicly i did not understand. please explain for better understand. thank you.

Comment: If you don't minimise it, it will minimise you :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

Comment: You must before know what is an stack overflow.

Comment: Please don't repost questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334948/how-to-minimizing-stack-overflow

Comment: ok. i am sorry for that. its my first time to be here that is why facing some problem.

Comment: "Filling an array from both sides" is not a common C idiom, and no one here is able to link that concept to stack overflow for you.  Either this is advice for a particular situation which makes no sense out of context, or you misunderstood the person, or he/she is just wrong.  In any case, just forget about that conversation.  If there's something you'd like to know about stack overflows, formulate a complete question (with code if possible), check google, then post your question on this site.

Comment: sorry for my bad question. now how can i reopen ??? any suggesion? please help i am new here. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack is where automatic variables are allocated

You can overflow it by allocating huge objects `int x[10000000000]` or with very deep levels of recursion.   The stack can be further limited in multithread environment's stack allocation per thread

The way to avoid allocating on the stack is to have a pointer and allocate on the heap using malloc (this is the the C version of calling new)  but this increases code complexity by requiring a matching call to free.

The way to reduce deep recursion is by possibly finding a shallower (generally more efficient) recursive algorythm.   Possibly filling the array from both sides is results in shallower recursion.

The generally better way however is to translate the recursive algorythm to an iterative (looping) equivalent (which can generally be done with the optimized recursion as well).  Looking at a trivial example:

The following recursion:

```
unsigned mult(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    return b ? a+mult(a, b-1) : 0;
}
```

Becomes the following iterative equivalent:

```
unsigned mult(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned ret=0;
    while (b-- > 0)
        ret+=a;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer for the question.

Comment: The question is about stack overflow minimization, not about stack overflow.

Comment: yeah. someone has told me i can do that by filling an array from both sides that is left to right   and   right to left, something like that. but basicly i did not understand. is it ok to describe my problem now sir ?

Comment: @MSTabrez - please edit your Question to be more precise and we will be better able to answer it.  Do not clarify it in comments.